# Finding a tree with adjacency matrix near a given matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, graph-distance

For defining a distance between trees, one can code them into $\mathbb{R}^n$ and use norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as distance. (For example we can use adjacency matrices as a tool for this coding) After that a natural question is given a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ how can we find a tree whose coding is as near as possible to this point. Is there any coding/encoding functions for trees or general graphs which can be used efficiently/approximately for this problem?

**Note**: The most relevant paper I'v found is the following which encodes the trees in a hyperbolic space and present a way of decoding points in that space back to trees:
[From Trees to Continuous Embeddings and Back: Hyperbolic Hierarchical Clustering](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2020/hash/ac10ec1ace51b2d973cd87973a98d3ab-Abstract.html)

Comment: I think you are looking for _graph embeddings_ (tree embeddings in your case), and the reverse operation.

Comment: @MatthieuLatapy Thank you for your useful comment. I actually did some searches on tree embeddings but could not come up with something on the reverse operations.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_edit_distance

Comment: @Dandelion Have you tried linking together vertices based on their (euclidean) distance in the embedding? As embeddings usually try to put linked vertices close to each others, in the case of trees, this may be sufficient.

Comment: @MatthieuLatapy I didn't get precisely what you said but it gave an idea to try however! Thanks!